# Mercurial : user friendly way to display exact revision number of files?

Tags: mercurial, identifier, revisions

When I was using Subversion as part of the build process I'd run an 'svn info' and capture the unique ID number and echo it to a header file for inclusion by other programs.  This made it easy for users to say for example, 'I'm running build 456' and given the number 456 I could always cross reference exactly what they were running.

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve the same thing with Mercurial.  'hg summary' displays an integer id as well as the hex hash code.  From what I was reading the integer id could be different for different people.  I'm supposing the hash code is unique, but it's not very user friendly.

Is the hg hash code the only unique way of identifying a particular version of files in Mercurial?

Thank you,
Fred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is the only way to uniquely identify a changeset.

More details in the documentation : [ChangeSet](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangeSet) and [ChangeSetID](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangeSetID)

If you want to use an integer number, I see two possible solution depending on your build process.

1. If the build always happens on the same machine (ie: same repository), you can use the integer id because it never changes on a particular repo (except if you do history rewriting)
2. If the build of a particular version only happens once, you can use a variable that you increment each time in your build script.

Comment: Sounds like it's safest to always use the hash, I can't guarantee builds will be done on only one machine.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that you *should* have a single machine doing the builds, to rule out differences due to OS differences, IDE/Tool differences, environment differences, etc, but this is orthogonal to your question and this answer.

Comment: @Lasse if you're building for various platform, this is not always possible, you will have one machine per platform most of the time.

Comment: Agreed, but then a unique number might not make much sense in the cross-platform way, would it? Basically, I didn't understand this scenario here as a cross-platform one.

Answer (score 1):

`hg id` command will give you needed changeset. You can add someoptions to command also, but most useful and permanent part is changeset id

For the same repo

```
>hg id -nibt
6c4d15d8cfbd 841 default tip

>hg id
6c4d15d8cfbd tip
```

you can also think about some commands, which support templating of output, and combine nice output from template-keywords mix: `hg help templating`

Example for already mentioned repo

```
>hg log --template "{rev}:{node|short}-{latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}" -r tip
841:6c4d15d8cfbd-1.3+3
```